# How to use changeEtherBalance from waffle-hardhat?

Tags: contract-debugging, ethers.js, hardhat, test, waffle

I want to check if the ether balance of an account decreased after the transaction using `changeEtherBalance` I tried to follow the waffle docs but couldn't do it either.

```
        await token.connect(addr1).mint(1, {value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1")}))
        .to.changeEtherBalance(addr1, -(ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1"))
        );
```

Error:

`Error: overflow (fault="overflow", operation="BigNumber.from", value=-100000000000000000, code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.5.0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found what I should have done, it's pretty simple:

```
await token.connect(addr1).mint(1, {value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1")}))
        .to.changeEtherBalance(addr1, ethers.utils.parseEther("-0.1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see more information [here](https://ethereum-waffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matchers.html). Basically you should send the recipient and the amount:

```
await expect(() => wallet.sendTransaction({to: walletTo.address, value: 200}))
  .to.changeEtherBalance(walletTo, 200);
```

Comment: But I want to check the new balance of the wallet that sent the value, so the result is going to be less than the original one.

Comment: Then I dont think `changeEtherBalance` is what you need to use, you need another validation thats checks the new balance and compares it with the previous one

Comment: I know I can do it by simply using `ethers.provider.getBalance(address)`, but really wanted to try using this method. Thanks anyway :)